# How to assert that every item in collection is within range

Tags: arrays, groovy, junit4, hamcrest

I have a Groovy array that will get a set number of random Integer Values.  And I want to assert that each item in the array has a value within the given range.  I'm trying to use Hamcrest Matchers. So my test looks like this:

```
@Test
void testShouldReturnArrayOfStats(){
    def results = pg.rollStats()
    assertThat results, everyItem(both(greaterThan(0)).and(lessThanOrEqualTo(6)))
}
```

When I run the test I get an assertionError

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: every item is (a value greater than <0> and a value less than or equal to <6>)
 but: was [<6>, <3>, <5>, <4>, <3>, <2>]
```

I've tried some variations of this but I'm not getting a passing test.  just by looking at the "But:was" portion of the error I can seen that all 6 values meet the requirements, but the test still fails.

I've not used Groovy or Hamcrest for very long so I'm sure that I'm missing something.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you just use groovy?

```
assert results.every { it in 1..6 }
```

Comment: Yes, I believe that works.  I'm still new to groovy, and I'm trying to incorporate some additional tools all at the same time. So in this case simple groovy assertions give the results I'm looking for.  Thanks